# how to pass target branch while creating merge request using git command line

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to create merge request from git command line  using below command

`git push --set-upstream origin branch-name  -o merge_request.create`

This creates merge request to master branch. But i want to create merge request to particular branch say "develop". How can i pass the target branch? How to assign to one person for review through git command line?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this notion is specific to Gitlab (you do at least have the tag here). Git itself has no notion of "merge request"; GitHub and Bitbucket use "pull requests" and those are created exclusively through their web interfaces, not via options sent during `git push` (their pull request concept predates push options).

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the target branch for a merge request too:

```
git push --set-upstream origin branch-name  -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=develop
```

This information is available on the GitLab website:  https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/merge_requests.md#create-mr

Comment: Thank u :) this works... i am  trying to add assign as well using below command

```git push --set-upstream origin branch-name  -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=develop -o merge_request.assignee=XXX YYYY

```
I tried with mail id as well but doesnt seems to work. For assignee i shld use display name or name starting with @ symbol or mail id

Comment: What did you use for providing assignee @user2900572

Comment: i was looking for this command for months! thanks!!!